# Adding button to controlgroup dynamically on every list item takes too long jquery mobile

Tags: performance, cakephp, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-listview

I am quite new to jquery mobile so this might be a trivial question. The fact that documentation is not centralized for jquery mobile is making me post this on stackoverflow.

Currently, I am trying to load a listview and every item of the listview has the following structure. The options button is a controlgroup button with variable number of buttons below it, again received from the JSON.

Currently there are about 250 objects and they are obtained from the server over an 85 KB JSON. Due to the dynamic nature of the content caching data is a bit tricky.

I am running into a problem wherein its taking almost 15 seconds to load this page. To find out the reason causing it I added timestamp values within the for loops that create the list items dynamically.

Interestingly the main bottleneck - which is upto 12 out of the 14 seconds is taken while creating the HTML for the controlgroup.

Here is an image of the options button to give you an idea about the HTML

I am keen to know why rendering dynamic control groups on list items is causing so much delay. I do not know how to cache the controlgroup since, the grouped buttons are also dynamic and are received from the JSON.

[image]

<[image]

I look forward to your feedback on this,

Thanks 
Rajat

**EDIT Code Snippet Added. I use this routine to generate every list item**

foreach ($jsonArray AS $item) {

## Show the adapter

```
echo '<li>';
if($item['reactionCount'] > 0) {
    echo ' <a href="/planner/reactionbox/id:'. $item['jobId'] . '">';
    if(isset($item['requiresAction'])) {
        echo ' <span class="ui-li-count redBubble" style="background:#088A08"> </span>';
    } else { 
        echo ' <span class="ui-li-count redBubble" style="background:#6E6E6E"> </span>';
    }
} else {
    echo ' <a href="/planner/job-details/id:'. $item['jobId'] .'" name=\"job' . $item['jobId'] . '\">';
}

echo '<img style="float:left; padding: 11px 0px 0px 11px; width: 66px; vertical-align:middle;" 
        src="' . (($item['imageUrl'] != '') ? $item['imageUrl'] : '/img/website/profilephotodummy.png') . '" alt="dummyphoto" />
        <h3>' . $item['firstLine'] . '</h3>
        <p><strong>' . $item['secondLine'] . '</strong></p>
        <p>' . $item['thirdLine'] . '</p>
        <p class="ui-li-aside"><strong>' . $item['optionalLine'] . '</strong></p>
        </a>';

if(isset($item['actions'])) {
    echo '<div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" style="margin-left: 15px;" data-mini="true">
    <select data-native-menu="false" data-theme="b" data-inline="true" data-mini="true" data-icon="gear" onchange="doJobAction(\'' . $currentUrl . '/\'+this.value); this.selectedIndex=0;">
    <option>' . __d('website','opties',true) . '';

    foreach ($item['actions'] AS $value) {

        # for every action from the JSON generate an action button dynamically ...
        if($value == 'annuleer_opdracht') {

            echo '<option value=" ' . $currentUrl . '/cancelJob:' . $flexbox['jobId'] . ' ">annuleer</option>';

        } else if($value == 'zoek_opnieuw') {

            echo '<option value="' . $currentUrl . '/newSearchJob:' . $flexbox['jobId'] . '">zoek opnieuw</option>';

        } else if($value == 'publiceer_externe') {

                                                            echo '<option value="' . $currentUrl . '/openForFreelancer:' . $flexbox['jobId'] . '">publiceer externe</option>';

        }
    }
    echo '</option></select></div>';
}
echo '</li>';
}
```

Comment: have you tried loading everything without calling any enhancement method and then just call one command `$('[data-role=content]').trigger('pagecreate')`.

Comment: Consider using other profiling methods to find your bottleneck, such as Chromes' built-in Profiles tab.  That may tell a different story and point out your problem.  Also, you may want to add some of your code for an example.

Comment: Hi @shanabus: I have edited the post with a code snippet. I am using cakephp in combination with jquery mobile and as you can see the list items are generated dynamically. If I remove the section under $item['actions'] which generates the control group then the page takes 2-3 seconds to load 250 items. However with that on it takes 15 seconds to load up the page

Comment: When you say "the section under $item['actions']", do you mean the code inside the `foreach` loop?  How many items are in that array, just the 8 you show above?

Comment: Yes, I mean the for loop. Currently I am parsing through 250 to 300 items and each $item has 3 actions.